# Generators of the monodromy generating braid groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, braid-groups, hecke-algebras, reflection-group

I'm reading the article 'Complex reflection groups, braid groups and Hecke algebras', by Broué, Malle and Rouquier, but I need some help with the 'generators of the monodromy' they defined and that generate the braid groups. In proposition 3.4 they use generators of the monodromy around hyperplanes to define a central element (a generator of the center, actually), but I would like to define these generators explicitly.

I tried to do this for $r\in \{1,2\}$, but I'm affraid I'm not understanding the definitions of a generator of the monodromy, so I'm unable to define these loops by a formula. I've tried to google 'generator of the monodromy'and I haven't been lucky, it seems it is not a common term for these kind of loops.

If someone could help me, I would be very grateful.